# Migration undefined local variable or method ` t'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

Hello I've scaffolded a migration, everything's nice, but when I `rake db:migrate` I get the following  error message on the shell:

```
==  CreateClients: migrating ==================================================
-- create_table(:clients)
--  t()
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined local variable or method ` t' for #<CreateClients:0x00000102a5a7c8>

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

Here's the migration file in the **db/migrate** directory:

```
# encoding: UTF-8

class CreateClients < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :clients do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :adress
      t.integer :telephone
      t.string :email
      t.text :comments
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :clients
  end
end
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Any chance of posting the full error? This is probably a gem issue making Active Record not run as expected. Above snippet looks fine.

Comment: It's rails 3.1.1. I've added the full message error as Ben requested it.

Comment: Maybe try running 'rake --trace db:migrate' to get a full stacktrace, see if that's any more enlightening.

Comment: The full stacktrace show me that the problem comes from active record.I forget to mention that I've updated my gems with rvm while they were first installed without rvm.So is this a conflict version? I've added a stacktrace snippet(it's too long).

Comment: and that migration file is an exact paste of the migration you're trying to run?  I'd expect to see this error if you'd forgotten the |t| bit on line 5...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this same error before as well. Are you using Devise? If so, try adding this:

```
t.confirmable
```

That fixed the issue for me.

And it will add these fields to the db when you run the migration:

```
confirmed_at :datetime
confirmation_token :string
confirmation_sent_at :datetime
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  Hopstream, I don't use devise, but this answer solved the problem

Comment: Maybe not directly, but one of the gems you're using is most likely dependent on it for authentication.

Comment: I'll try to figure out which gem it is.